# Firebase: get new collection when data was changed

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

In my Angular/Firebase/GraphQL application I have next query:

```js
async getAllCategories() {
      return await tryCatchWithApolloErrorAsync(async () => {
        const categories = await adminService
          .firestore()
          .collection(api.categories)
          .get();

        return categories.docs.map(category => category.data()) as Category[];
      })
    }
```

This query returns the whole collection when I call it in my component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this._categories = this.categoriesService.getAllCategories().pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe((categories: Category[]) => {
      this.categories = categories
    })
  }
```

But when the collection was changed, for example, if some of the elements were removed or edited, I need to refresh the page to get the new collection.

How can I make the component always get the latest version of the collection?

Comment: Well `take(1)` will limit the observable to single omit right?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky it does not matter, even if I removed this it works in the same way

Comment: Okay, so `tryCatchWithApolloErrorAsync`, how is the implemented? Is that a single call to Apollo or is that a realtime subscription? If it's a single call, then you won't get realtime subscriptions.

Comment: `tryCatchWithApolloErrorAsync = async (bodyFnAsync) => {
    try {
        return await bodyFnAsync();
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw new apollo_server_1.ApolloError(error);
    }
};`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky so it's just a Promise

Comment: Okay, so `get()` only [gets data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) so you'd need to update your code to listen for [realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), at minimum removing `get()`, but you may need to restructure your try/catch logic/helper. Once you have tried that, reformat the question with your updated code.